# The sequence $\sin \left({n\pi}\over 6\right)$ has the superior limit $L=1\dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am studying limit points of a sequence now, and have some misunderstandings. Here's an exercises I have: The sequence $$\sin \left({n\pi}\over 6\right)$$ has the superior limit $L=1$and the inferior one $l=-1$. Then it is written that: the sequence has 7 limit points:$$l_1=-1,\space l_2={1\over2},\space l_3=-{\sqrt3\over 2},\dots \space l_7=1$$ 
What does this limit points represent? Thank you very much.

Comment: i suggest you to edit this to: $\sin(\frac{n\pi}6)$

Comment: I have to admit I laughed when I saw \cdot \cdot \cdot

Comment: I'm perplexed, how is it that $$\overline{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}}\left\{\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{6}\right)\right\}$$ has 7 limit points?

Comment: @bd1251252 Period 12 and 5 values achieved twice in each period make for 12-5=7 distinct values.

Comment: Distinct values representing what?

Comment: @bd1251252 ?? Know what a *periodic* sequence is?

Comment: You might be talking sideways here. @bd1251252 the question is about the limit points of the original sequence not its limes superior.

Comment: @Did I know what a periodic sequence is, I'm just wondering where the 12 and 5 are coming from. yes, I'm totally ignorant on the subject of superior and inferior limits, I've had the wikipedia crash-course before though.

Comment: @bd1251252 My previous comment deals only with the number of distinct values and does not touch on limsup and liminf. If you want to understand where 12 and 5 are coming from, posting cryptic comments is not the best way to proceed. Re 12: what might be the period of the sequence of general term sin(n.pi/6), according to you?

Comment: @Did I apologize for my earlier comment(s), just learning. I'm not sure what the period of $$\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{6}\right)$$ would be...I would assume $\frac{2\pi}{\left|\frac{\pi}{6}\right|}=12$, so there's the 12...what about the 5?

Comment: @bd1251252 Re the period, note that $\sin((n+12)\pi/6)=\sin((n\pi/6)+2\pi)=\sin(n\pi/6)$. Re the 5, see my answer.

Comment: @Did Okay I see, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_n=\sin(n\pi/6)$.

The question in the title asks for the limsup of the sequence $(x_n)$, this is solved by noting that if, for every $n$, $x_n\leqslant1$ and, for every $n$, $x_{12n+3}=1$, then $\limsup\limits_nx_n=1$.

The question in the body asks why the sequence $(x_n)$ has $7$ limit points, this is solved by noticing that it has period $12$ and it achieves $5$ values twice in each period, hence there are $12-5=7$ distinct values.

Comment: Sorry for a probably stupid question, but can you give me, please, an example?

Comment: Example of what?

Comment: You said that period 12 and 5 achieved twice in each period  make for 12-5=7 distinct values, what do you mean ? Sorry but I dont understand.

Comment: The period is 12, a priori this makes for 12 numbers. But amongst these, 5 values are achieved twice and 2 values are achieved only once. Thus 5+2 distinct values.

Comment: Alternatively, *compute explicitely* the first values of the sequence and observe what you get...